# Scrapy crawling 0 pages, even though elements exist

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape transfermarkt.nl with the help of scrapy.
The website used to give a 404 error so changed the settings to

```
HTTPERROR_ALLOWED_CODES = [404]
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36"
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
```

Now when I run

```
import scrapy

class TransferMarketScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'transfermarket'
    starts_urls = ['https://www.transfermarkt.nl/heracles-almelo/kader/verein/1304/saison_id/2022/plus/1']

    def parse(self, response):
        for player in response.css('div.grid-view table.items tbody tr').get():
            #player number
            try:
                player_number = int(
                    player.css('div.rn_nummer::text').get().strip()
                )
            except ValueError:
                player_number = 'NA'
            except AttributeError:
                continue


            yield {'player_number': player_number}`
```

I get Crawled 0 pages, eventhough when I check using scrapy shell, the response do return values. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

you re not sending the request you need to parse you need to add this

```
 def start_requests(self):
        starts_urls = ['https://www.transfermarkt.nl/heracles-almelo/kader/verein/1304/saison_id/2022/plus/1']
        for url in starts_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: It's not necessary in this case. Read [this](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?#scrapy.Spider).

Comment: Hmm that doesn't change anything and in tutorials I dont see this line?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. You wrote `starts_urls` instead of `start_urls`.

**EDIT:**

This other thing you might want to change is to remove the `get()`.

```py
import scrapy


class TransferMarketScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'transfermarket'
    start_urls = ['https://www.transfermarkt.nl/heracles-almelo/kader/verein/1304/saison_id/2022/plus/1']

    def parse(self, response):
        for player in response.css('div.grid-view table.items tbody tr'):
            #player number
            try:
                player_number = int(
                    player.css('div.rn_nummer::text').get().strip()
                )
            except ValueError:
                player_number = 'NA'
            except AttributeError:
                continue

            yield {'player_number': player_number}
```

Comment: Changed that, but dont think that matters

Comment: I does matter, see the edit. (BTW, you can lose the try except and use [default](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.SelectorList.get))